# Load values every 5 minutes and pass to another method java android

Tags: java, android

I want to check the data every 5 minutes and I want to pass this to another method but since it throws exception and has api version it's hard to pass the abc(mValue) to a callback

```
  String Value = "";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void abc(String mValue) throws ParseException {
        Date date = new Date() ;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm") ;
        dateFormat.format(date);
        if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date) + 5).after(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)))) {
            Value = mValue;
            data(mValue);
            actualData(mValue);
        }else{
            someMethod();
        }

    }


private void xyz(String mValue){
Call<somemethodname> call1 = pass.user(xyz(mToken)) //I want to pass it like this but it is not possible so it would check the above condition 
}
```

If there is any other way to check the time function, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Timer` is there is some task that you want to repeat every `x` amount of time.

Here is some reference code. Just make sure to cancel the timer when done.

```java
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //what you want to do
  }
}, 0, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));// Wait 0 ms before doing the action and do it every 1000ms (1second)

timer.cancel(); // Stop the timer when done
```

Also another note, if you want to run something on UI thread then your code will be modified as follows

```java
Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your logic here...

        // When you need to modify a UI element, do so on the UI thread. 
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.
               
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)); // End of your timer code.
```

`getActivity()` is usually for Fragments, if you are already inside an `Activity` then you can simply use `this`

Comment: As noted on the class Javadoc, the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes have been supplanted by submitting `Runnable`/`Callable` task object to a `ScheduledExecutorService`.